# what is the maximum range of citizens band radio computation

Tags: radio

i have been computing the maximum distance for a citizen's band radio. i don't know if my computation is correct because the answer is so large, appx. 280000km. what do you think is wrong with my computation please help. or please teach me how to solve for the maximum range for citizens band radio. thanks for your help :D [image: my computation]

Comment: The distance to the moon is 384000km, so it's not going to work for that trip :(

Comment: You missed the S/N ratio, but YES with this system you can communicate with half of our planet people (since this distance it is about half of earth circumference)...but not in earth!!

Comment: ...and of course you need to take into account that radio waves tend to travel in straight lines so for an observer on the ground with eye level at h = 5 ft 7 in (1.70 m), the horizon is at a distance of 2.9 miles (4.7 km). For an observer standing on a hill or tower 100 feet (30 m) in height, the horizon is at a distance of 12.2 miles (19.6 km).

Comment: 11 meters is going to behave a lot like the 10 meter ham band, being in the range where the ionosphere will bounce signals back to earth when activated by the sun - when that happens, terrestrial communication when far beyond line of site is possible.  In contrast, when the ionosphere is inactive, signals will go right out into space - there are a few spacecraft which operate in that frequency range. It's arguably a poor place for the CB service to have been allocated - something in VHF/UHF that rarely propagate over the horizon would have been better, but more expensive back in the day.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. so what do i need to do to derive for the typical maximum range of citizen's band, the 20-30 km? thank you guys :D

Comment: 3-5 miles i mean

Answer (score 1):

At sunspot maxima, propagation to the antipodes at 20+MHz is certainly achievable with 4W, and signals at the receiving end can be surprisingly strong (50uV into 50 ohms is not unusual). Radio hams do it all the time!

With 100W, earth-moon-earth (EME) is achievable at higher frequencies, using the moon as a passive reflector, although higher powers (~1kW) are normally used.

Answer (score 0):

The standard equation used for free space link loss is: -

Loss (dB) = 32.45 + 20\$log_{10}\$(f) + 20\$log_{10}\$(d)

Where f is in MHz and d is in kilometres. This equation tells you how many dB of power loss you can expect at a given distance with a given carrier frequency.

At 28.6MHz and 280,000 km the loss is 32.45dB + 29.13dB + 108.9dB = 170dB.

If you are transmitting 4 watts this is 36dBm so the signal at your receive antenna is going to be -134dBm. If you have a bit of antenna gain then you might see -130dBm.

If you only want 5kHz bandwidth (and the receiver is designed with that in mind) you'll need a receive sensitivity of about -120dBm. Given also that you'll want about another 20dB gain to account for fade margin, you are going to be about 30dB short of achieving 280,000 km.